# What is the acceptable number of javascript external linked files

Tags: javascript, html

What is the acceptable number of javascript external linked files, within html.
And may a browser happen to not download external js file. If yes then why it may happen.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take in consideration that every script that is external will take time to load and the server that serves it may be offline.

You should consider including only the scripts you use on the current page and not all libraries in the world for small things.

An acceptable number of external files is **0**. From my opinion.
If you want your webpage to run smoothly you should not consider loading anything external.

External files are often included for testing purposes when you don't want to save scripts on localhost, css (eg: **jQuery** and **jQuery UI**). But on live production you should have them on your host/server. Maybe in future the external server will not be available anymore.

A browser does NOT choose what to download, it downloads what he is asked. But if a script fails, or there are actions in that script that require an additional library and that library isn't available, the browser will stop loading and will give errors.

Comment: All inline script may also not good in these days, so maybe just 2, one jQuery lib(or other lib), then 1 for extra payload. All put on footer

Comment: What you mean "take time to load". Since the js files are text, so the time for them to download will not be long. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You are missing the fact that for each file the browser has to resolve a DNS, connect to a server and download that file.

Comment: The real problem that I am getting into is. I am making entire ajax website, and I have huge number of scripts. I want to separate them logically in files so working on them become easy. What would you suggest me to do? Maybe I should consider to use other method than separation of code in files. I am new in javascript.

Comment: You separate them in multiple files for easier edit, but you should consider using an cache system. An programming system that takes all javascripts and combines them into one temporary file.

Comment: Can you give me a reference or tutorial on cache system? thanks.

Comment: It's called Script Combining, eg: [phpflair](http://code.google.com/p/phpflair/) for `PHP`, for .Net I'm not sure, but you can see this [video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-35/aspnet-ajax/using-script-combining-to-improve-ajax-performance), just search Script Combining for your server-side programming

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is quite complicated. You have to take into account caching, number of simultaneous requests and things like authentication.

The disadvantage of inline scripts is that you can't take good advantage of caching. If you move your scripts to external files revisiting users may still have your files in cache and the page will load faster for them. How many scripts you should have depends on the number of simultaneous requests a browser will make (typically 4), the size of the scripts and execute complexity. Keep in mind that CSS files, or basically any resource, *on the same domain* counts towards this limit as well. You may ignore stylesheets with `media="print"` as modern browsers will delay loading.

If you have more than 4 scripts the 5th script will only start loading when one of the other 4 have been loaded. If this script contains some `on dom ready` event code it will be delayed. You could consider merging scripts or changing the order in which they are loaded.

Another problem to be well aware of is updates. If you update your scripts and users still have the old one cached you're going to run into problems. Some users might even get some of the newer scripts and some of the older scripts. Make sure you have a mechanism in place for this. I've found **fingerprinting** to be really useful in cache management.

You could consider a lazy loading principle where you first only load the most basic scripts for showing what the user absolutely must see. Then load other scripts in the background as they are needed.

Then there are 3rd party services like Google Maps, you can't actually cache these files because they change over time and may contain authentication steps to prevent abuse and such. You have limited control over these scripts.

Overall it depends on the kind of website you're making. If you're making more of a business application a relatively long load time may be acceptable. If you're making a fancy promotional site, load time is absolutely key and inline scripts may be for you.

This is quite an advanced topic, don't worry about it too much unless you run into actual performance issues. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare).

Comment: Thanks for you detailed explanation. The real problem that I am getting into is. I am making entire ajax website, and I have huge number of scripts. I want to separate them logically in files so working on them become easy. What would you suggest me to do? Maybe I should consider to use other method than separation of code in files. I am new in javascript.